# Unable to remove null values from dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df containing 2 columns (State and Date). The State Columns has names of various states and the Date Column has `NULL` Values. I want to remove the rows containing these `NULL` values

I tried using multiple options like `drop_na()`, `filter()` and `subset()` using `!is.null()` but nothing seems to work. Can someone point out where am I going wrong.

```
mArkets <- market_data[c(1,4)]
mArkets <- mArkets %>% filter(!is.null(Date))
```

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Vm4.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0):

They're not `NULL` at all, looks like they're '' (an empty string).

```
mArkets <- mArkets %>% filter(!is.null(Date) | Date!='')
```

would work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I pull the value as mArkets[1,2] it gives the Output as NULL. Not sure what am I missing over here

Answer (score 0):

I feel that they might be empty strings:

```
mArkets <- mArkets[!is.null(mArkets$Date) && mArkets$Date != '']
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I pull the value as mArkets[1,2] it gives the Output as NULL. Not sure what am I missing over here

Comment: @Phant5x Edited my answer, should work now.

Comment: @Phant5x Does it work?

Comment: Nope doesn't seem too

Comment: @Phant5x What does `print(df['Date'][0])` output?

Comment: @Phant5x What's the output?

Comment: Its throwing the entire date column

Comment: @Phant5x What' that? Show me

Comment: @Phant5x Please check out my recent edit!!! It works!

Comment: Yes its working now. Thank you for the help!!!